# Windows Forms designer compilation symbol: does it exist?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

Does Windows Forms for full Windows OS has some compilation symbol so when designer is going to compile code I can conditionally compile with preprocessor directives?

Compact Framework projects have so, but I don't find such symbol in a full Windows Forms project.

Sample code:

```
#if DESIGNTIME

#endif
```

Comment: The designer doesn't compile code.  So no.  Use this.DesignMode in your code.

Comment: But check that CF Windows Forms has a **NETCFDESIGNTIME** compilation symbol. The designer doesn't compile code, but designer needs a up-to-date compiled code.

Comment: It is just set in the project properties.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Conditional compilation symbols setting.  http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/netcfdesigntime-t1298386.html

Comment: @Hans Passant, thank you for the info, but I really knew that. And it's not about adding custom symbols. _The symbol_ must be defined by the caller of the compiler - _Visual Studio designer_ - somehow.

Comment: What does this mean "Designer is going to compile code"? Designer does not compile a code, it generates it. Maybe you are talking about design/runtime mode of container? But this applies only to controls. The question is not clear.

Comment: @Alex Even if it applies to controls or not, in Compact Framework you've a symbol called **NETCFDESIGNTIME** so if you use an **#if** preprocessor directive, code within this will be compiled and/or executed (I don't know exactly how does it work right now) if it's VS designer.

Comment: OK, but what exactly you want in standard Windows Forms (not compact)? Designer doesn't complie anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question won't have a whole answer, because it seems such compilation symbol isn't present in Windows Forms.

At the end of the day, the answer is **No, there's no designer compilation symbol in Windows Forms**.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the properties of your project you can set arbitrary conditional compilation symbols at the top of the 'Build# tab. Build in are #DEBUG and #TRACE but you can define your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I believe you didn't get the point of my answer. Actually I know I can define arbitrary, custom compilation symbols, but do you really think defining custom symbols would make them usable for detecting a compilation started by Visual Studio designer? ;)

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it. I had this problem years ago, too. The designer would crash because one of my custom controls did not have a meaningful empty constructor (got a null reference as a result). I think I built around it with a custom variable like Hans is suggesting.

Comment: Yeah, I knew this property too.. But I'm looking to know if there's something like Windows Forms in Compact Framework, let's see if it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

From [.Net source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,054dea3ede7caf94,references):

```
public static bool DesignTime( Control myControlOrForm )
{
    return myControlOrForm.Site != null && myControlOrForm.Site.DesignMode;
}
```